# how to print out the definition of a procedure in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there a way in oracle to see what a procedure's structure is? I'm trying to log and am running procedures and wanted to store the actual procedure structure in my log.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could query the `ALL_SOURCE` table

```
SELECT text 
  FROM all_source
 WHERE owner = <<owner of procedure>>
   AND name  = <<name of procedure>>
 ORDER BY line
```

If you are dealing with a procedure that is inside a package

```
SELECT text 
  FROM all_source
 WHERE owner = <<owner of procedure>>
   AND name  = <<name of procedure>>
   AND type  = 'PACKAGE BODY'
 ORDER BY line
```

will give you the text of the package body.  You could also get the text of the package specification using a `TYPE` of "PACKAGE"

Answer (score 7):

[dbms_metadata package](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#i1015856), [get_ddl function](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#i1019414), perhaps?

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCEDURE','<yourproc>','<schema>') FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT TEXT, LINE FROM ALL_SOURCE WHERE 
    NAME = UPPER('$name') -- the table also has an owner field to track the user
    ORDER BY TYPE, -- type is generally procedure, but there are functions and 
                   -- more complex structures as well, such as PACKAGE
    TO_NUMBER( LINE )
```