# What do parameters like the following one in a SELECT query do?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a query like this:

```
SELECT personas.IDDNI                                                      iddni,
       PERSONAS.NOMBRE                                                     NOMBRE,
       PERSONAS.APELLIDO1                                                  APELLIDO1,
       PERSONAS.APELLIDO2                                                  APELLIDO2,
       PERSONAS.ANTIGUEDAD                                                 ANTIGUEDAD,
       VACACIONES(personas.IDDNI, to_char(add_months(sysdate, 0), 'YYYY')) VACACIONES
FROM   personas personas,
       trieniosobservaciones t
WHERE  personas.iddni = t.iddni
       AND ( personas.iddni = '47656567' )
```

I'd like to know what `VACACIONES(personas.IDDNI,to_char(add_months(sysdate,0),'YYYY')) VACACIONES` does in the query, as depending on the `personas.iddni` value it can return one row or give the following error:

> The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: VACACIONES is obviously a function that you or somebody else added to your database. Use SQL Developer to open that function code and see what it does.

Comment: On a side note: Why are you joining trieniosobservaciones? You don't seem to be using it in your query. And `add_months(sysdate, 0)` is the same as a mere `sysdate`.

Comment: As thorsten says, `VACACIONES()` is a custom function. Contain your database administrator to find out more. If you tag your DB vendor, we might be able to tell you how to identify the function definition

Comment: For Oracle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167307/how-to-print-out-the-definition-of-a-procedure-in-oracle

Answer (score 1):

`VACACIONES` is a user-defined function that takes two arguments, an `IDDNI` value for a person and a year. Beyond that, we cannot tell you what it does because it is a user-defined function and we do not have access to your database or the source code of the function.

You can find the [source-code of the function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000292/1509264) using:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   all_source
WHERE  name = 'VACACIONES'
AND    type = 'FUNCTION'
ORDER BY owner, line;
```

and then you can work out what it does.

Comment: `DESCRIBE VACACIONES` should also do the trick and give the definition of the function.